# Ionic DateTime component displaying day name as 'undefined'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My DateTime component is displaying my day-name as undefined:

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Data</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDD DD MMMM" pickerFormat="DD MMMM" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**APP.MODULE to apply translations:**

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
   monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar\u00e7o','Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
   monthShortNames: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
   dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Ter\u00e7a-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'S\u00e1bado' ],
   dayShortNames: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'S\u00e1b' ]
})
```

**Print** 
[image]

Anyone knows why?!

Comment: it cause because of pickerFormat ..

Comment: @SarasaGunawardhana i removed the pickerFormat attribute and it still undefined.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include year in a picker and then day name will be displayed, because week day depends on year and month and can't be calculated without this data

```
displayFormat="DDD, MMM D" pickerFormat="YYYY MMM DD"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. I've solved it this way:

**Page.html:**

```
    <i>{{getDate(item.date)}}</i>
```

**Page.ts:**

```
    getDate(date) {
        // sunday, monday, tuesday...etc... by russian
        let dayNames = ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"]; 
        date = new Date(date);
        let day = dayNames[date.getDay()];
        return day
    }
```

I hope it help you!

Answer (score 0):

I gave in this way. Day was showing in the display.

```
<ion-datetime display-format="DDD, MMM DD, YYYY" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxYear" picker-format="MMM DD, YYYY"
                formControlName="startDate"></ion-datetime>
```